# Socket appear as closed in boost asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

For the following client code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <system_error>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    const std::string target_URL { "google.com" };
    int target_port {80};

    boost::asio::io_service io_service_test;

    std::string port_str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(target_port);

    tcp protocol = tcp::v4();
    tcp::resolver::query resolver_query(protocol, target_URL, port_str, tcp::resolver::query::numeric_service);
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_test);

    try {
        tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(resolver_query);
        const boost::system::error_code ec;
        tcp::socket socket(io_service_test);

        std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> current_socket = std::make_shared<tcp::socket>(io_service_test);

        boost::system::error_code err_code;
        (*current_socket).open(protocol, err_code);

        if (ec.value() != 0) {
            std::cout<<"Error in open socket"<<std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        asio::connect(*current_socket, iterator);

        tcp::resolver::iterator end;
        while (iterator != end)
        {
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *iterator++;
            std::cout << "endpoint " << endpoint << std::endl;
        }


        std::cout << "Socket " << ((*current_socket).is_open() == 0 ? "is open" : "not open") << std::endl;
        

        (*current_socket).shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, err_code);
        (*current_socket).close();

    }
    catch(const boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error> &ex){
        std::cout << "Error code = " << ex.code()  << " message: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    catch (const std::system_error &e) {
        std::cout << "Error code = " << e.code()  << " message: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return e.code().value();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why for this code is obtained "Socket not open" message, and farther why cannot be reading some data from this socket?

Comment: Note you have the declaration `const boost::system::error_code ec;` where `ec` is not used again until the line `if (ec.value() != 0) {` just after the `open` call where you pass in `err_code` to it instead. That appears to at least explain why your check for the socket open failure doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

A few notes:

- **never** compare error code *values*. Instead, compare error conditions: read the Introduction paragraph [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/system/doc/html/system.html) to learn more
- no need for dynamic allocation, `tcp::socket` is also movable
- no need for iteration, `asio::connect` already iterates
- no need for resolver query object (in fact, I think it was deprecated)
- I prefer to pass the resolvers `result_type` directly, instead of first taking the iterator out of it
- no need to open the socket, it will be automatically opened by `asio::connect` if required, as per documentation
- catch `system_error`, not the `wrapper type (I'm not sure where that came from)
- prefer `asio::io_context`, `io_service` has been (long) deprecated. In fact, since you don't actually run any async work, you might want to use `system_executor`.

With these simplifications in place the code executes the way I'd expect it:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a9ba8bcf897b12e)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using tcp      = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main() try {
    const std::string target_URL{"google.com"};
    asio::io_context  ioc;

    tcp::socket   s{ioc};
    tcp::resolver resolver{ioc};
    connect(s, resolver.resolve(target_URL, "80"));

    std::cout << "Socket is_open:" << std::boolalpha << s.is_open() << " remote:" << s.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

    boost::system::error_code ignore;
    s.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ignore);
    s.close();
} catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
    std::cout << "Error code message: " << se.what() << std::endl;
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cout << "General exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Printing locally:

```
Socket is_open:true remote:142.250.179.206:80
```